# Swiftmailer email queue with multiple functions calling the class - and gmail SMTP time-limits

Tags: php, smtp, swiftmailer

I'm trying to wrap my head around this:

I have many functions in my code-base that initiate sending an email with [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).  Let's say that within a 1 second period, 1000 users initiate different functions that end with one (or more) email being sent out.  How does the class capture all of these 1000 requests and queue them, without any DB access?  If it was a single function initiating the 1000 requests, I understand how this entire array is iterated through by the class - using the "bulk sending" rules I have defined (100 at a time, with a 2 minute break, for example).  But I *do not* understand how it does it from multiple users initiating the email.

That said, what are some good limits if I'm using a Gmail Apps SMTP server to send all of my email?  I'll be nowhere near the 1000 requests per second that I use in the example above, but in the future there could be 100 in a few minute period.

Thanks all.

Comment: Queue? Why do you say that class queues something?

Comment: They have a "throttler" plugin, so I have to assume that they are queuing things somehow to make this happen?

Comment: Well that's a lot of guessing. Consider reading about the plugins in general and then about the throttler plugin in specific first. Your sense is not wrong that without a database you can not share some queue across multiple clients.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to a "database"; your options are:

1. fall back to flat files for managing the queue (i.e. essentially use a series of flat files as your own database, sort by time stamp and send in order; those arriving in the same second going in any order, possibly alphabitcal given a random unique name?
2. use memcached to store the e-mails in memory - WARNING: will lose all infomration should the memcached server get restarted.

1000 requests in a second is a fair few; my general rule of e-mails is never more that 2000 in an hour. GMail do advertise their limits at http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22839 at 500 unique e-mail addresses (to prevent spam) so this may be a problem for you. There are other providers that allow more, but you need to pay.